# HtmlAgilityPack как убрать пробелы

Tags: c#, htmlagilitypack

Текст парсится в хаотичном порядке, одно слово на первой строке, второе на 2 и т.д. В оригинале это все идет в одну строку с небольшим отступом. Как убрать все пробелы и сделать нормальный вывод текста? c#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<table style="width: 100%;" class="data">














        <tbody><tr>





                    <td>Текст7</td>









                    <td>Дата</td>





                    <td>Тип</td>





                    <td>Текст6</td>





                    <td>Текст5</td>





                    <td>Текст4</td>





                    <td>Текст3</td>





                    <td>Текст2</td>





                    <td>Текст1</td>


        </tr>
```

Comment: Примеры приведите, по описанию не понятно в чём проблема.

Comment: Делаю парсинг какого то блока. В нем множество тегов и окончательный вид в форме такой: текст1 на одной строке, текст2 идет ниже текса1, текст3 еще ниже. то есть в колонку вниз, с множеством пробелом и отступов.  Я же хочу сделать так, чтобы у меня было: текст1  текст2  текст3, все это в одну строку

Comment: Ну так спарсите строки сначала в массив отдельных элементов, потом соедините их через `string.Join`.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, что спарсить от отдельности все элементы тега <td> ? Их там очень много. И потом соеденинить?

Comment: Именно это и имею. Не уверен прямо все td или не все, зависит от страницы. Но это намного проще, чем пытаться как то иначе деформировать текст страницы.

Comment: Покажи исходный html.

Comment: @Monk Просмотрите пожалуйста изображение, которое я добавил.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Добавил код в начало темы.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov поможете? Код добавил.

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял, нужно выбрать и объединить содержимое текстовых узлов.

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var node in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants().OfType<HtmlTextNode>())
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(node.Text))
        sb.Append(node.Text.Trim()).Append(' ');

sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);
```

Вариант с LINQ:

```
var textNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode
    .Descendants()
    .OfType<HtmlTextNode>()
    .Select(n => n.Text.Trim())
    .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s));

var result = string.Join(" ", textNodes);
```

Вместо `DocumentNode` возьмите нужный узел.

Возможно, `Trim` не нужен (зависит от содержимого). Возможно, не нужны проверки `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` (также зависит от содержимого).

---

На представленном в вопросе html этот код выдаёт результат:

> Текст7 Дата Тип Текст6 Текст5 Текст4 Текст3 Текст2 Текст1

Comment: я добавил картинку в начало темы. нужно убрать пробелы с самого начала, и после каждого слова. Чтобы осталась одна строка и в ряд шли названия.

Comment: @Dmitry - это полностью рабочий код. Я дополнил ответ, показал результат. Что ещё нужно?